# Unable to read hadoop/hive external s3 table from spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hadoop, awss3transfermanager

All of sudden I am unable to read the hive external s3 table from spark,  I noticed there are subfolders got created under few partitions.

I hope there is any parameter or setting can be configured so Hadoop doesn't create these subfolders.

when I manually delete subfolders from s3, I can read table. but need to find a way so these subfolders won't get created randomly in future.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `mydb.mytable`(
    `id` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
    `attribute_value` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
    `attribute_date` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
    `source_id` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
     PARTITIONED BY (`partition_source_id` int)
     ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde' 
     STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
     OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
     LOCATION 's3://path/my_data'
     TBLPROPERTIES ('transient_lastDdlTime'='1567170767')
```

When I run `select *` query I get:

> error: 
>   java.io.IOException: Not a file: s3://my_path/partition_source_id=11/1
>   1 statement failed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this DDL creates subfolders.
If there is some job to load data into 's3://path/my_data' and executes DDL add partition on mydb.mytable, I think you should take a look the job.